# In blazor render an exception does not go to <ErrorContent>

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In the page rendering it is throwing an exception. I expected that to be caught and displayed. But it isn't.

I have App.razor as:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h1>Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</h1>
                    <p>You may want to try logging in (as someone with the necessary authorization).</p>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And MainLayout.razor as

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
...
    <ErrorContent Context="error">
        @{
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var useFallback = true;
            if (error.Data.Contains("Category"))
            {
                var data = error.Data["Category"];
                if (data is Type category)
                {
                    var logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(category);
                    logger.LogError(error, "Error: {guid}", guid);
                    useFallback = false;
                }
            }
            if (useFallback)
            {
                Logger.LogError(error, "Error: {guid}", guid);
            }
        }

        <h1>Unexpected Error (sorry)</h1>

        <p>
            The program has encountered an unexpected error (yes there are expected errors). This error has been
            logged and we will look at it.
        </p>

        <p>We suggest you <a href="/identity/account/LogOut">logout</a> and then log back in if you wish to try again.</p>

        <p>If you want to contact us, please include the following error id: @guid when you do.</p>

    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

This works for a lot of cases. But not this one. What am I missing to be able to display an exception thrown in rendering? At present it's a blank page - which is not good.

**Additional info:**

It is occurring inside this razor code where `context.DataItem` is null. It throws a NullPointerException.

```
<ExDataGrid Data="@Data"
            KeyFieldName="Id"
            CssClass="dx-datagrid"
            PageSize="@PageSize"
            DetailRowDisplayMode="DetailRowMode">
    <Columns>
        <DxGridDataColumn ReadOnly="true"
                          FieldName="EventFlyweight.Name"
                          Caption="Event">
            <CellDisplayTemplate>
                @{
                    var job = ((VolEventItemModel)context.DataItem).EventFlyweight;
                    var url = $"/Event/Profile?id={job.Id}";
                }
                <DisplayFlyweight Data="@job"
                                  Link="@url"
                                  SizeMode="SizeMode.Large" />
            </CellDisplayTemplate>
        </DxGridDataColumn>
```

Comment: What is the exception in this case? Are you sure it's from the actual rendering?

Comment: The error is probably in an `async void` code block, maybe on an event handler in a service.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis It's occurring in the rendering code (updated the question to provide more info). Anyways, where/how can I catch/process this so I can provide a friendly error message and log the exception? TIA

Comment: This is inline code which the Razor Compiler builds into a component class.  You need to look at the generated code to get a better picture of what is being generated.  Add `<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>` to the project file and look at the generated code.  Can `Data` take a null gracefully?  I would move the whole of `((Vol...` into your code section and make sure I'm handling nulls correctly.  Do you have Nullable enabled?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have nullability enabled and make use of it. And I'll add code to handle Data being null although it should be impossible here (obviously it isn't). But the reason for my question - is how can I catch this exception so I can log it. Because otherwise this will happen silently and all I'll know in production is a page didn't display.

Comment: I can't repeat this problem.  Any code examples I've tried that generate `NullPointerException` in the manner your code is doing so, flows the error up to the `ErrorBoundary` component.  My guess is therefore that the `DXGrid` stuff is handling the error thrown by the `CellDisplayTemplate` RenderFragment internally and sinking it.